# How to prevent Activity from staying in the task stack after "quit", without using android:noHistory?

Tags: java, android

Currently, I have an `Activity`, which is used to configure home widget. It is shown during

1. When user place the home widget on desktop for the 1st time.
2. Or, when user tapped on the already shown home widget.

This is the Manifest for the Activity.

```
<activity android:name="com.xxx.widget.NoteListAppWidgetConfigureFragmentActivity"
    android:taskAffinity="com.xxx.launcher"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

1. We specific `android:taskAffinity` explicitly, as we do not want this configuration activity, interference with our main app flow. Hence, We want this activity to be launched at separate task stack, by using `android:taskAffinity`.

---

When user "quit" the configuration Activity, we would like the "com.xxx.launcher" task to be cleared off completely.

Reason is that, without clearing the task, user can always check the recent task list, re-launch the old `NoteListAppWidgetConfigureFragmentActivity` again and then overwrite current widget settings with old settings. **This is an unwanted behaviour.**

---

Currently, there are 2 ways for user to "quit" the `NoteListAppWidgetConfigureFragmentActivity`

1. Pressing a `Button` control of the activity.
2. Pressing system back button.

### Pressing a `Button` control

We notice by executing `finishAndRemoveTask` when the `Button` control pressed, we can clear off the task.

### Pressing system back button

We cannot figure out a way to clear off task stack. We even try the following code, but it **does NOT** work.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (isFinishing()) {
        this.finishAndRemoveTask();
    }
}
```

---

We do not want to use `android:noHistory="true"`, because it causes `onActivityResult` malfunction. We can no longer perform `startActivityForResult` in `NoteListAppWidgetConfigureFragmentActivity`

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical
> trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the
> user will not be able to return to it. In this case,
> onActivityResult() is never called if you start another activity for a
> result from this activity.

Do you have an idea, how we can  prevent Activity from staying in the task stack after "quit", without using `android:noHistory`?